# ipython notebook image slide

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to know how to make image list from

```
SimpleCV.ImageSet(1.3)
```

to a ipython notebook (1.0.dev) list

A live example is [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4706057), line near "In [22]".

It's seems to call some predefined function

```
imgslides()
```

But I can't figured it out where and how did he done it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a IPython feature, the author probably wrote it himself. I suggest you contact him directly. It seem to be only a iframe of tihs adresse : http://epi.whoi.edu/esr/imgshow.html